# IndexIgnore only in specific directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2.2

I have a web server where I use mod_autoindex. In the root folder, there is a `.htaccess` file which has a `IndexIgnore` rule in it. However, I only want this rule to apply to the root directory, not the sub folders. Is there any way to do this?

**Note:** I have Apache 2.2 installed, which means there is no `IndexIgnoreReset` rule in that version.

Comment: Is `IndexIgnore` the only thing in your root `.htaccess`? Because if so, just create a `.htaccess` file in your sub directories and put `RewirteEngine On` in each of them. Therefore ignoring the rules from your root.

Comment: @Lag No, I also have `ErrorDocument`s, custom icons and `IndexOption`s in the `.htaccess` file.